# Why doesn't my implementation of NSUserDefaults work under iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've read and watched many tutorials on `NSUserDefaults` in the iPhone OS/iOS SDK, but I can't seem to get my own implementation working.

Right now, I'm building a simple counting application that I'd like to have load the last counted number when the application loads. *However,* `NSUserDefaults` has a different idea in mind. Does anyone know why my preference loading method keeps returning `(null)` in an `NSLog`?

Thanks in advance! :)

**CounterViewController.m** (abridged)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

// yadda yadda yadda interface setup here...

    if ([self retrieveCount] == 0) {
        count = 0;
    } else {
        count = [self retrieveCount];
        NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", count];
        [label setText:temp];
        [temp release];
    }


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

int count = 123; //whatever it might be when the user exits the application, set every time the "+" or "-" is tapped

- (void)writeCount {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [prefs setInteger:count forKey:@"countKey"];
    [prefs synchronize];

}

- (int)retrieveCount {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [prefs synchronize];
    int loaded = [prefs integerForKey:@"countKey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", loaded);
    return loaded;
}
```

**CounterAppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
    [CountrViewController writeCount];
}
```

(Since I'll only be retrieving a value from one key, I decided to not have any input into the method.)

If this is confusing in any way, please let me know! I'll be glad to provide clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need to call `-synchronize` before you read from the defaults, only after you've written to them.
Your `NSLog` may actually be the culprit here—try `%d` rather than `%@`. `%@` is for printing objects, like an `NSString` or an `NSNumber`; an `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: As a side note, synchronize is automatically called at periodic intervals, it's so reliable I haven't ever called it, but to be save I would call it once before the application terminates.